# portable drive is read only

Tags: hard-drive, read-only

I recently switched from windows 10 to Linux, and I have a portable drive that just has images, video, and my code files. I have Linux installed on my main drive (SSD). now when I'm trying to access my portable hard drive it says read only file system. i have scoured the internet looking for fixes but to no avail. Please help I'm a Linux newbie.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any OS/release details, this site doesn't provide generic GNU/Linux help.  You may have mounted the file-system RO yourself (you gave no details of how it was mounted), or an unclean file system was detected in which case GNU/Linux (Ubuntu and flavors) will make it RO (read-only) to prevent damage due to the unclean fs (file-system) state.  If done at terminal, error messages are show, if done using a GUI then messages are in logs.  This is vague as I don't know your OS/release details.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and I think I mounted the drive using the default file explorer. I think the file system is NTFS

Comment: Try the command `mount | grep "type "` and look for your drive to make sure.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Your question is not clear. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1209121/edit) your question and add the information asked in the comments above. You can copy and paste errors directly from the terminal into the question and format them as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 0):

By default, NTFS is not writable by Linux.

Install the package ntfs-3g, then unmount the filesystem and remount it with *`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -orw /dev/sdb1 /mnt`*

You will be asked to enter your password. Enter your user's password and hit *`Enter`*.

You can replace *sdb1* with the actual device given for your external drive, and replace */mnt* with wherever your desired mount point is.

You can also create an entry in /etc/fstab to make it always use ntfs-3g rather than the in-kernel ntfs driver. Or you can create a blacklist entry for modprobe so ntfs module never gets loaded.

Comment: It gave me an error saying "mount: only root can use "--options" option" when I tried to remount it. Can I just mount it using the file explorer?

Comment: This site is for Ubuntu. ntsf-3g is installed by default in Ubuntu and ntfs partition is normally writable from Ubuntu.

Comment: @user68186: you're probably right. It is installed on my machine, I just don't remember whether I installed it manually or not.

Comment: @LandoSpuk: put _`sudu `_ in front of the command I gave you, and it will ask you for your password. Enter your user's password. Unless your user is limited, that should work.

Comment: @user68186: I edited the answer as you suggested. I expect it to succeed, especially if, as you stated, ntfs-3g is default on Ubuntu. You never know how "new" a self-proclaimed newbe is. I should have spelled out that you have to be the superuser (use sudo) in order to set options for mount. Depending on the device, one might have to be superuser to mount in any case.

Comment: If my updated answer solves your problem, please mark it as the answer.